# How do I use Numpy views when doing scalable statistics bootstrapping

Tags: python, numpy, dask, scalability, statistics-bootstrap

I have a large dataset that I process using `xarray`+`dask` for scalability. These libraries work great for all of my calculations, except for one. The final step is to perform some statistics bootstrapping (on the largest dimension) and then calculate a variance over it.

The way I do it looks like this:

```
idx = xr.DataArray(
    np.random.randint(0, projections.n.size, (sample_count, sample_size)),
    dims=("sample", "n"),
)

bootstrapped_variations = xr.concat(
    [projections.isel(n=i).var(dim="n").sum(dim="ReIm") for i in idx], dim="sample"
).chunk("auto")
```

This work for some sample sizes, but does not scale to larger ones and I get out of memory errors. I guess the main problem is creating so many new arrays when calling `isel`. The thing is that they should get reduced immediately, since we calculate their variance.

What I would like to do, is to create a `numpy` view of such a single sample, so as to not allocate new huge arrays in memory. Here I use advanced indexing, so a copy is returned.

It can be slower computationally, but I just wonder if it can be done. Perhaps there are some other efficient ways to do bootstrapping on large datasets? From what I've read `np.random.choice` also returns a copy, not a view.

Comment: You should consider posting this question in discourse.pangeo.io.